# git merge local with remote master using terminal

Tags: git, github, terminal, osx-mavericks

*Sorry for asking a question that has probably been asked a thousand times. But I don't even know enough to know what a similar question might look like.*

- master (on github.com) has changes that my local repo does not have
- my local repo has changes that master does not have
- what is the git command (s) for synching the two?

I am using a mac terminal (osx-mavericks)

If I understand terminologies well, mine is not a forked branch, it's really just a local copy of master. The divergence occurs because I forgot to pull master before making some changes on the local repo. Now I need to merge but a push will not work.

**master**: the remote repo on github.com

**local repo**: the code on my local computer

Comment: This is confusing. You should specify, in your question, that `master` is the name you've given to a *remote*, because `master` is a name traditionally reserved for a *branch*.

Comment: You need to tell us more about the branches involved. What does `git branch -a` tell you?

Comment: When I do `git branch -a` it returns `*master` `remote/projectname/master`

Comment: Ok, and to be sure, what does `git remote -v` tell you? Also, do you have write access to that remote repository on GitHub? Did you create it yourself?

Comment: `projectname https://github.com/projectpath (fetch)`  `projectname https://github.com/projectpath (push)`

Comment: and yes, I own the remote repo that is on GitHub: I have write access. I have been using it for some days now. This is the first time I get into this situation.

Answer (score 2):

This is a three-step process:

1. commit the local changes
2. pull from remote
3. push to remote

Commit the way you normally do:

```
git add --all .
git commit -m "the local changes that I have made"
```

Then pull the way you normally do:

```
git pull somerepo master
```

I take it you already know how to commit and how to pull based on the conversation

To be safe, after pulling, I like to immediately push.

Answer (score 2):

To begin, make sure your local repo is aware of everything that is in the remote repo: run

```
git fetch
```

Now, based on your question and comments, I'm guessing your local repo looks something like that:

[image]

The `master` branch living in your local repo has somehow diverged from the `master` branch living in your local repo. Git won't allow you to push your (local) `master` branch to the remote, in that case.

By "syncing the two", I'm assuming you mean combining the changes on `master` and those on `projectname/master`.
You have basically two ways of doing that: merge or rebase.

Before proceeding, make sure that you're on `master` by running

```
git checkout master
```

(In the following, I'm assuming that your local repository knows your remote repository under the name `projectname`.)

### Option 1: merge

Run

```
git merge projectname/master
```

Your repo will then look like this:

[image]

After that, just run

```
git push projectname master
```

and `master` and `projectname/master` should be up to date (i.e. pointing to the same commit):

[image]

### Option 2 (more advanced... proceed with care): rebase

Run

```
git rebase projectname/master
```

and you repo should look like this:

[image]

After that, just run

```
git push projectname master
```

and `master` and `projectname/master` should be up to date (i.e. pointing to the same commit):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detail explanation. I looks like it should work. So +1. But I already implemented using the answer by @KonsolLabapan and it works. I am sure more people may find your explanation more useful as a teaching/learning tool.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure how you have created local GIT system.

As per your description, you created a local repo ???? And you want to sync it with a repo on github.com ??? Syncing 2 repos is something non traditional.

However, I am providing solution for having repo (remote master branch designated as origin/master) on github.com and a local tracking copy of remote master branch designated as local master branch on your system.

Checkout output command **git remote show origin**. It should output as follows.

```
HEAD branch: master
   Remote branch:
        master tracked
   Local branch configured for 'git pull':
        master merges with remote master
```

If it is not, then you followed something else which is not conventional.

Have you created your local GIT system using either **git clone** OR **git init** ???

Conventional way :

1. Repo name on github.com = myrepo
2. **git clone user@github.com/myrepo.git**
3. Above command automatically creates a **local master** branch tracking to **remote master** which is nothing but the repo.
4. now you can other GIT operations such as add, commit, merge, push, pull and very importantly branching on your local GIT system.

Hope it will help.